# How one can show that the gamma function is a strictly increasing function on the interval $(1.4616,+∞)$.

Tags: real-analysis, gamma-function, digamma-function

How one can show that the gamma function is a **strictly** increasing function on the interval $(1.4616,+∞)$.

Comment: $(\ln u)^2x^{u-1}e^{-u}\gt0$ for all positive $u\not=1$, so $\Gamma(x)$ is concave up for $x\gt0$, hence strictly increasing to the right of its minimum.

Comment: @BarryCipra Why does this imply it's concave?

Comment: @ablmf, It's the integrand for the second derivative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f(x)=\Gamma (x) \implies f'(x)=\Gamma (x)\, \psi ^{(0)}(x) \implies f''(x)=\Gamma (x) \left(\psi ^{(0)}(x)^2+\psi ^{(1)}(x)\right)$$ If $x>0$, the only root of the digamma function is at $x_*=1.461632144968$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Roots_of_the_digamma_function)).

You could easily obtain this solution expanding the digamma function as a Taylor series around $x=1$ and use series reversion. Otherwise, use Newton method.

For this value , $f''(x_*) \sim 0.856974$ showing that  that it is a minimum.