# How to prove that $\Gamma(x) \leq x^x$ for $x \geq 1$

Tags: calculus, analysis, inequality, reference-request

Where can I find a (simple?) proof that $\Gamma(x) \leq x^x \,\,\,\, \forall x \geq 1$?

$\Gamma(x)$ is the Gamma function defined as

$$ \Gamma(x) = \int_0^\infty t^{x-1} e^{-t} \, \mathrm{d}t
$$

Comment: You could try differentiating the difference and showing that the derivative is always positive.

Comment: You should also check out sterling approximation, he already proved that $$\log( \Gamma(x)) \leq x \log( x)$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the substitution $t = xu$, we have
\begin{align*}
\Gamma(x) &= x^x\int_0^\infty u^{x - 1} \mathrm{e}^{- xu}\mathrm{d}u \\
&= x^x\int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{(x - 1)\ln u - xu}\mathrm{d}u \\
&\le x^x\int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{(x - 1)u - xu}\mathrm{d}u \tag{1}\\
&= x^x
\end{align*}
where in (1) we have used $\ln u \le u$ for all $u > 0$.

We are done.

Comment: Very nice! (Apart from using `\mathrm{e}` for the Euler number :)

Comment: @MartinR Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

For $1 \le x < 2$ we have
$$
 \Gamma(x) \le 1 \le x^x \, .
$$

For $x \ge 2$ and $n  = \lfloor x \rfloor$ is
$$
\Gamma(x) \le \Gamma(n+1) = n!  \le n^n \le x^x 
$$
because the Gamma function is increasing on $[2, \infty)$, see for example [How one can show that the gamma function is a strictly increasing function on the interval $(1.4616,+∞)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3464439/42969)